# Dependency issues with actionpack upgrading rails from 4 to 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Trying to upgrade rails to 5.0.0 and continue to receive the below error(first of quite a few).  I deleted my lock file, and tried adding `gem('actionpack', '=5.0.0')` to my gemfile and ran `bundle install`. It seems like `5.0.0` would meeet all the requirements below? I tried `gem('actionpack', '~>5.0.0')` as well and it just added `actionpack (~> 5.0.0)` to the output with the same error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers was resolved to 0.10.12, which depends on
      actionpack (< 6.2, >= 4.1)

    haml-rails was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)

    lograge was resolved to 0.11.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.2)
```

Edit2: Results with `gem('rails', '= 5.0.7.2')` and removing `actionpack` from Gemfile.  Ran `docker-compose run web bundle update rails`

```
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers was resolved to 0.10.7, which depends on
      actionpack (< 6, >= 4.1)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      formtastic (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.2.13)

    haml-rails was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7) was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
        has_scope (~> 0.6) was resolved to 0.7.2, which depends on
          actionpack (>= 4.1)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7) was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 5.3, >= 4.2)

    lograge was resolved to 0.10.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4)

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.7.2)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      ransack (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.8.9, which depends on
        actionpack (<= 5.1.1, >= 3.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.5.0, which depends on
      responders was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 5.3, >= 4.2.0)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 3.8.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
```

Edit 3: Showing full output

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers was resolved to 0.10.7, which depends on
      actionpack (< 6, >= 4.1)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      formtastic (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.2.13)

    haml-rails was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7) was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
        has_scope (~> 0.6) was resolved to 0.7.2, which depends on
          actionpack (>= 4.1)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7) was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 5.3, >= 4.2)

    lograge was resolved to 0.10.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4)

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.7.2)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      ransack (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.8.9, which depends on
        actionpack (<= 5.1.1, >= 3.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.5.0, which depends on
      responders was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 5.3, >= 4.2.0)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 3.8.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    acts_as_paranoid was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
      activerecord (< 6.0, >= 4.2)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      kaminari (< 2.0, >= 0.15) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
        kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
          activerecord

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.7.2)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      ransack (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.8.9, which depends on
        activerecord (<= 5.1.1, >= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    acts_as_paranoid was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
      activesupport (< 6.0, >= 4.2)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      arbre (>= 1.1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

    haml-rails was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.0.1)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7) was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
        has_scope (~> 0.6) was resolved to 0.7.2, which depends on
          activesupport (>= 4.1)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      kaminari (< 2.0, >= 0.15) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 4.1.0)

    lograge was resolved to 0.10.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4)

    paperclip (>= 5.0) was resolved to 6.1.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.0.7.2)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      ransack (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.8.9, which depends on
        activesupport (<= 5.1.1, >= 3.0)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 3.8.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0)

    slack-ruby-client was resolved to 0.13.0, which depends on
      activesupport

    spring was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    cucumber-rails was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

    haml-rails was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
        nokogiri (>= 1.6.0)

    paperclip (>= 5.0) was resolved to 6.1.0, which depends on
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.0) was resolved to 0.3.9, which depends on
        nokogiri (~> 1)

    roadie-rails was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      roadie (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.4.0, which depends on
        nokogiri (~> 1.5)

    ruby-saml (= 1.8.0) was resolved to 1.8.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.10)

    twilio-ruby was resolved to 5.13.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (< 2.0, >= 1.6)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.7.2)

    rails_same_site_cookie was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
      rails (>= 4.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      railties (< 5.2, >= 4.2)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      coffee-rails was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
        railties (>= 4.0.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.5.0, which depends on
      railties (< 6.0, >= 4.1.0)

    factory_bot_rails was resolved to 4.11.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0.0)

    haml-rails was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.1)

    lograge was resolved to 0.10.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 4)

    roadie-rails was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      railties (< 5.3, >= 3.0)

    dotenv-rails was resolved to 2.5.0, which depends on
      railties (< 6.0, >= 3.2)

    quiet_assets was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.1)

    xipio was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 3)

    cucumber-rails was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 3.8.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7) was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
        railties (< 5.3, >= 4.2)

    activeadmin (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      jquery-rails (>= 4.2.0) was resolved to 4.3.3, which depends on
        railties (>= 4.2.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.5.0, which depends on
      responders was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
        railties (< 5.3, >= 4.2.0)

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.7.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby":
  In Gemfile:
    ruby (~> 2.4.3.0)

    cucumber-rails was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.8) was resolved to 1.11.3, which depends on
        ruby (>= 2.5.0)
```

I think I need to update ruby, so my docker image as well.

Comment: Deleting your lock file doesn't seem like a good idea as you could update gems that maybe aren't required to be updated. Why don't you just update to `5.0.7.2` which is the last `5.0.x` version? Also, how do you have defined those gems you mentioned in your `Gemfile`? Finally, it shouldn't be necessary to add `gem('actionpack', '=5.0.0')` if you already have your rails version defined.

Comment: @AlterLagos all of them gems mentioned are in the Gemfile, but do not have a version specified.  I have removed `gem('actionpack', '=5.0.0')` and added back the lock file.  I added `gem('rails', '= 5.0.7.2')` in my gem file.  I'm using docker ran `docker-composse run web bundle update rails` and received the error above(will edit question)

Comment: Strange, I don't see an aparent conflict in the info you've displayed. What about using `docker-compose run web bundle update rails actionpack `?

Comment: @AlterLagos still running into the same issue.  There's several `bundler could not find compatible...`.  I had thought they were all independed, but maybe not.  Will post whole output above.